# Xcode simulator, link is invalid sending SMS in HTML webpage, why?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, xcode

I'm not familiar with xCode, I'm using the iPhone 6 simulator to view a simple site in Safari. The webpage has a link which should open up the simulators SMS messenger:

```
   <a href="sms:12345678?body=Hello my friend">Send SMS</a>
```

However, in the simulator when I click on this link I get following alert:

> "Safari cannot open this page because the address appears to be
>   invalid"

My question is, do I get this message because I'm missing some services of files for the simulator, or I'm I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't open SMS application with simulator. you should use a real device.

Answer (score 1):

If you see XCode Simulator apps then you will realize that there is no Messages app. So in simulator there is no app which can handle URL of type sms: and that is the reason you are getting an alert from Safari.